# How to imply a specific group in multiple groups

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice

I would like to text a question but every group has three items,so how could I indicate in question header that I'm implying just an option of three items?

For example:

> Which three of following were the main social classes in medieval Europe?
>   *Welche drei der folgenden waren die wichtigsten sozialen Klassen im mittelalterlichen Europa?*

A) x, y, z

B) k, l, m

C) x, l, k

And for the definetely true information, do we use "waren" or "zählt man als ..."?
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: @CarstenS Regardless of how bad the title was, I don’t think you should have edited it to read *this question needs a title* …

Comment: @Jan, you may be right, but it achieved the desired result ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get it out of the way: Use *waren* here if there is an answer that is comprehensive — i.e. there are no classes outside of those mentioned in the answer list. Otherwise, use *zählt man zu den …*, i.e. if there is at least a fourth class.

Your sentence with *welche drei der folgenden* works. But the entire thing is still improveable. You are probably best with a more liberal translation:

> Welche Dreiergruppe benennt die wichtigsten sozialen Klassen im mittelalterlichen Europe?